# How to execute click() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

This code basically takes 'textmoney' and figures out how much a person makes a year. to execute this function you have to press enter. I also have a div called 'moneydiv' that will do the same function, but it seems if i have both functions in the same script neither will work. How would i code to have the user to be able to do both functions? How would i code the click() with the div?

Jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var $demo = $('#demo');
    var $textMoney = $('#textmoney');
    var $moneydiv = $('#moneydiv');

    .keydown(function(e) {
         if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            var money = $(this).val();
            if (isNaN(money) || money === '') {
                $demo.text('You aint enter no $$$$$$');
            } 
            else {
                var dailyE = $(this).val() / 365;
                $demo.text('$' + dailyE + ' per day');
                 }
            } 
           else if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $demo.text('');
            }
           }).mouseover(function() {
           $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
           }).mouseout(function() {
           $(this).css('border', '1px solid grey');
        });

  });
    </script>
```

Comment: where is your html and the div click handler

Comment: the script above has syntax error, please share your current script... if possible create a demo at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: There is a way to simulate click on a html tag using `$(selector).trigger('click');` I guess you can use it make it work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the click function

```
$("#id").click(function () {
 // your code here
})
```

I recommend visiting [Jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to learn more.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If moneydiv and textmoney need to execute the same function. Then i advice you to do it this way.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var $demo = $('#demo');
    var $textMoney = $('#textmoney');
    var $moneydiv = $('#moneydiv');

    function todo(){
        var money = $textMoney.val();
            if (isNaN(money) || money === '') {
                $demo.text('You aint enter no $$$$$$');
            } else {
                var dailyE = $textMoney.val() / 365;
                $demo.text('$' + dailyE + ' per day');
            }
    }

    // on enter key
    $textMoney.keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            todo();
        } else if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $demo.text('');
        }
    }).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid grey');
    });

    // on click 
    $moneydiv.click(function(){    
        todo();
    });

});
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to fire the press event of the "textmoney" when you click the "moneydiv" and you can do like this.

1. Register the press event of "textmoney".

```js
$('#textmoney').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    var money = $(this).val();
    if (isNaN(money) || money === '') {
      $demo.text('You aint enter no $$$$$$');
    } else {
      var dailyE = $(this).val() / 365;
      $demo.text('$' + dailyE + ' per day');
    }
  } else if ($(this).val() === '') {
    $demo.text('');
  }
}).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid grey');
});
```

2. Then trigger the keypress event when click the moneydiv.

```js
var keyPressEvent = $.Event('keypress');
keyPressEvent.keyCode = 13;
$('#moneydiv').trigger(keyPressEvent);
```

However, another simple implement is that you can extract the logic into a function and bind the function to both the click and keypress event.

Hope that can help you!